# EntitySet could not be found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

I'm working on an MVC site using EF4 as my data source. I've had no problems with other projects with EF4 until today. I'm getting an error stating EntitySet name Entities.Sites could not be found. I have another EDMX file for another dataset that is set up nearly the same (with different entity names) and it works fine when I try to run a LINQ query against it.

My EDMX has 2 tables (site and page) with a 1 to many association from the site to page table. Everything compiles fine, but in runtime, it's almost like the datamodel fails on every property list population. I do have Lazy Loading enabled (It's a .NET 4 project).

I stepped through the code on the designer class and it fails when it gets to a call like this

```
if((_Pages == null))
{
     _Pages = base.CreateObjectSet<Page>("Pages");
}
```

I have not altered the code in the designer.cs. I'm at a major wall with this.
Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Comment: Make sure you have the namespaces sorted out. In an MVC project you also have a `System.Web.UI.Page` class, which could be clashing with your entity name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try renaming your entity *Page* to something else, like EntityPage (for example) to see if this resolved it. As stated by @Yakimych this could simply be a case of Namespace clashing

Comment: I tried renaming them, but no luck. Originally I was trying to have one EDMX per Area in my project, but that seemed to cause the problem. As soon as I ran all my data calls into on data model, it works fine. I tried namespacing out my data models, but that didn't work either.